# Content not centered in properly way

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, width, margin

I'm working in a design and I want to center its content

```
.container_12 {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.grid_3 {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and html as follows:

```
<div class="container_12">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 grid_3 box-3">
             <h2> </h2>
             <img>
             <div class="inside">
                 <div></div><a></a>
             </div>
         </div>
             and 2 divs in same hierarchy


      </div> 
      </div>
```

but it didn't center properly 
the problem doesn't show in a large screen but in smaller screens it shows awfully, see image:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide js fiddle with the sample of code so we can look into it.

Comment: looks like you're using Bootstrap. If so, you're mixing everything, `container_12` should be container, then you could simply align `.box-3` to center. Also, when you're asked to add code, please ADD CODE, not pseudocode, help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was wanted to center 3 column in small screen less than 760 PX where the body width 770 PX as example 
with specified property  to container like that  `{width: 850 px;}` with

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

but in general this wouldn't work because of the specified width is bigger than the real one and exceed it so there's no margin to auto it and center the content which found in div 
so just specify the width for specified media query

```
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .container {

margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 660px;
}
    }
```

in most cases the bootstrap solve this problem but in a little cases like this it broken
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to the container.

```
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

And remove.

> margin: 0px auto;
>   padding: 0px;